# required attribute won't work on form and e.preventDefault won't work on submit button

Tags: javascript

So I  have a form in the footer that I wanted to display a dialog box when the user submits their information. Before doing this I wanted to prevent the page from refreshing so I added `e.preventDefault` then I wanted to make sure all the inputs were filled out before the user could submit. So I added `required` to all of the inputs. Then I added code to reveal a hidden dialog box `dialog.style.display = 'block';` doing this however will make it so the user can submit without entering any info. So I changed my event on the submit button from `submit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {` to `submit.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {` This fixes the `required` problem, but now when I hit submit I can't view the dialog box and `e.preventDefault();` doesn't work?

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links .link');
const linksArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.links div'));
const header = document.querySelector('header');
const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');


for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
 navLinks[i].addEventListener('click', changeColor);
}

for (var i = 0; i < linksArray.length; i++) {
 linksArray[i].addEventListener('click', shuffle);
}

function changeColor() {
 let hexArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
 let hexColor = '#';

 for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*hexArray.length);
  hexColor += hexArray[random];
 }

 header.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
 header.style.backgroundColor = hexColor;

 setTimeout(function() {
  header.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/canada.jpeg)';
 }, 2000);
}

function shuffle() { //  Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm
  for (let i = linksArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)); 
    [linksArray[i].innerHTML, linksArray[j].innerHTML] = [linksArray[j].innerHTML, linksArray[i].innerHTML]; 
  }
}

submit.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
 const address = document.querySelector('.address').value;
 const city = document.querySelector('.city').value;
 const dialog = document.querySelector('.dialog-wrap');
 const close = document.querySelector('.close');

 dialog.style.display = 'block';
 document.querySelector('.dialog-name').innerHTML = name;
 document.querySelector('.dialog-address').innerHTML = address;
 document.querySelector('.dialog-city').innerHTML = city;
 close.onclick = () => {
  dialog.style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector("form").reset();
 }
 
})
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Verdana';
 box-sizing: border-box;
 color: #63889b;
}

* {
 outline: 1px solid red;
}

/*------NAV-----*/

nav {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 padding: 25px 0;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px rgb(99, 99, 99, 0.5);
}

.brand, .nav-links {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.brand {
 margin-left: 6%;
}

.logo {
 max-width: 70px;
 max-height: 45px;
 margin-right: 25px;
}

.nav-links {
 position: relative;
 margin-right: 6%;
}

.nav-links .link {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-right: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}

.nav-links .link:hover {
 color: #014263;
}

/*-----HEADER-----*/

header {
 margin-top: 92px;
 background-image: url(img/canada.jpeg);
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 padding-top: 7%;
 padding-bottom: 25%;
}

.header-info {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 width: 423px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 padding: 35px;
 margin-left: 10%;
}

header p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

header p:first-child {
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}


/*-----MAIN-----*/

main {
 display: flex;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.col {
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 padding: 50px 0 40px 0;
}

.col p {
 width: 65%;
 font-size: 1.25rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.col img {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-3 img {
 width: 280px;
 height: 155px;
}

.col-3 img, .col-3 h3, .col-3 p {
 position: relative;
 top: -8px;
}

.col-2 img, .col-2 h3, .col-2 p {
 position: relative;
 top: 30px;
}

.col-1 {
 margin-left: 7%;
}

.col-3 {
 margin-right: 7%;
}

h3 {
 text-align: center;
}

/*------FOOTER-----*/

footer {
 font-family: 'Helvetica';
 background-color: #63889b;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 color: #fff;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.internal-links {
 padding-left: 15%;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.links div {
 margin:2px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.internal-links h4 {
 text-decoration: underline;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 margin-top: 30PX;
 color: #fff;
}

.links {
 font-size: 1.2rem; 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.form-wrap {
 padding-top: 30px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-end;
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

form {
 margin: 0 100px 0 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 100%;
}

input {
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
}

label {
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 padding: 3px 0;
}

button {
 margin-top: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 width: 50%;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 background-color: #1090d1;
 align-self: flex-end;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 4px 30px;
}

.dialog-wrap {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}

dialog {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 500px;
 height: 220px;
 border: none;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}

dialog div {
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 10px 0;
 outline: 1px solid #63889b;
}

dialog div:first-child {
 margin-top: 0px;
}

dialog .label {
 background-color: #63889b;
 padding: 7px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30%;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

dialog .info {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 5px;
 color: #000;
}

dialog button {
 border: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto auto 16px auto;
 padding: 7px;
}

dialog button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all .3s ease;
 background-color: #0675ad;
}

dialog div:last-child {
 outline: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
 .header-info {
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 width: 392px;
 margin-left: 7%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
 .col p, .links {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
 nav {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 .header-info {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  width: 363px;
 }

 .col-1 img {
  width: 270px;
  height: 132px;
 }

 .col-2 img {
  width: 280px;
  height: 107px;
 }

 .col-3 img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
 }

 .col p, .links, label {
  font-size: 1rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
 .col p {
  width: 85%;
 }

 .col-1 img {
  width: 230px;
     height: 112px; 
 }

 .col-2 img {
  width: 220px;
     height: 82px;
 }

 .col-3 img {
  width: 210px;
     height: 120px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 .header-info {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Chapman Automotive Skills Assessment</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <div class="brand">
  <img src="img/Logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
  <div class="comp-name">CHAPMAN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-links">
   <div class="link">Home</div>
   <div class="link">Sales</div>
   <div class="link">Blog</div>
   <div class="link">Login</div>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <header>
  <div class="header-info">
   <p>We are a company that does stuff.</p>
   <p>Car and web stuff.</p>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main>
  <div class="col col-1">
   <img src="img/car1.jpg" alt="car1">

   <h3>Some Header</h3>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo tempore quia enim quod, perferendis illum quae id, natus dolores temporibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, rem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col col-2">
   <img src="img/car2.jpg" alt="car2">

   <h3>More Stuff</h3>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo tempore quia enim quod, perferendis illum quae id, natus dolores temporibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col col-3">
   <img src="img/car3.jpg" alt="car3">

   <h3>Last Column</h3>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo tempore quia enim quod, perferendis illum quae id, natus dolores temporibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, ipsa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
 </main>
 <footer id="footer">
  <div class="internal-links">
   <h4>Internal Links</h4>

   <div class="links">
    <div>Page One</div>
    <div>Another Page</div>
    <div>Sales Page</div>
    <div>Page Three</div>
    <div>Keep Going</div>
    <div>Last One</div>
    <div>Just Kidding</div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-wrap">
   <form>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="name" required>
    <label for="Name">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="address" required>
    <label for="Name">City</label>
    <input type="text" class="city" required>

    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit Form</button>
   </form>

   <div class="dialog-wrap">
    <dialog>
     <div><span class="label">Name:</span><span class="dialog-name info"></span></div>
     <div><span class="label">Address:</span><span class="dialog-address info"></span></div>
     <div><span class="label">City:</span><span class="dialog-city info"></span></div>
     <div><button class="close">Close</button></div>
    </dialog>
   </div>
 </footer>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `submit` is an event of a whole form, not of its buttons. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Comment: Ok,  So if I use a click event How can I make sure my function doesn't run unless the inputs are filled out, and how can I make it throw an error like it was doing before when I had the required attribute on the inputs?

Comment: Just attach a `submit` event handler to the form element.

Comment: Sorry, @zerkms. You can definitely post your answer if you want. I can delete mine

Comment: @EvgeniyMalyutin I wouldn't bother posting one - MDN has a complete example already. But upvoted you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding event listener to a form instead of a submit button.

HTML

```
<form id="form">...</form>
```

JS:

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form');    
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
    const address = document.querySelector('.address').value;
    const city = document.querySelector('.city').value;
    const dialog = document.querySelector('.dialog-wrap');
    const close = document.querySelector('.close');

    dialog.style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.dialog-name').innerHTML = name;
    document.querySelector('.dialog-address').innerHTML = address;
    document.querySelector('.dialog-city').innerHTML = city;
    close.onclick = () => {
        dialog.style.display = 'none';
        form.reset();
    }

})
```